# Example for $\max_{\overline{U}} u<\max_{\partial U} \max(u,0)$ in the statement of weak maximum principle

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

The following is the statement for the weak maximum principle:

> [image]

where

> [image]

Here is my **question**:

> Could anyone give an example for the strict inequality in (11)? Why is it not true that
>   $$
> \max_{\overline{U}}u\leq\max_{\partial U}u^+=\max_{\partial U}u\leq\max_{\overline{U}}u?
> $$

Comment: $u$ might be strictly negative.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thank you for your *answer*!

Comment: @DanielFischer: Enlighten by your comment, I think I did have an answer to my trivial question and I put it as an answer. Because I don't think I deserve the credit so I put it as "community wiki". But people voted to delete it. Am I doing anything crazy? Or may I kindly ask you to turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: You're not doing anything crazy. It's a perfectly valid answer (unfortunately, so short that the system sent it into the review queue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel's comment, a quick example would be $u$ being a negative constant on $\overline{U}$.

Comment: @amWhy I disagree, Jack gave a concrete [okay, picking a specific constant like $-\pi$ would have been even more concrete] example, as was requested in the question. That makes a completely valid answer.

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks for you comment. Well then, it is short though, it does answer the question, doesn't it?... (Maybe more explanation would be better?) I had thought about the question for a while and didn't realize that it is that trivial. Now that I have written it down as a post, I thought it might be good to just leave it here. Anyway, *thank you* for your comment, and I'm really sorry for my trivial question...

Comment: @Jack I don't think your question was trivial. I will delete my comments. The last thing I intended to do was to come across as berating you or otherwise leaving you feeling attacked. Keep your post. :-)